# I can't send post data to another server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

this is my code right now:

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
        Dim client = New System.Net.WebClient()
        Dim postdata = New System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
        postdata.Add("username", "qweqwe")
        postdata.Add("password", "asdasd")
        Dim bytes = client.UploadValues("https://juzcode.com/post.php", postdata) ' exception here
        Response.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes))


    End Sub
```

However I'm getting exception "Unable to connect to the remote server". Am I doing something wrong?

Btw this is the code for http://juzcode.com/post.php:

```
<?php if($_POST["username"]==="qweqwe" && $_POST["password"]==="asdasd")echo "<b>success</b>";else echo "<i>failed</i>";
```

Comment: https://juzcode.com/post.php doesn't appear to be connectable-to - my browser happily timed out after a long wait.

Comment: @Will A for some reason my Firefox does that too. But it works fine on Chrome. I've no idea why, see my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on the web of using c# to post to PHP:

http://blog.brezovsky.net/en-text-1.html

Answer (score 1):

Put your code into a Try / Catch you may be trying to fight a loosing battle behind a corporate firewall.

Check the exception.